# Angular error TS2739: Type 'AbstractControl' is missing the following properties from type 'FormControl'

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I'm trying to add a formArray to my form, following [this article](https://netbasal.com/angular-reactive-forms-the-ultimate-guide-to-formarray-3adbe6b0b61a). The error I'm getting is pasted at the bottom and seems to be an issue with `[formControl]="devices.controls[i]"` on the input. The error is preventing me from serving my app but I can't figure out what is wrong with it.

**HTML**

```
<div formArrayName="devices">
    <h3>Devices</h3>
    <button (click)="addDevice()">Add Device</button>

    <div *ngFor="let control of devices.controls; index as i">
        <label>
            Device:
            <input type="text" [formControl]="devices.controls[i]">
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

**TS**

```
terminalNameInput = new FormControl();
devices = new FormArray([]);

addTerminalGroup = new FormGroup({
    terminalNameInput : this.terminalNameInput,
    devices : this.devices,
});

addDevice() {
    this.devices.push(new FormControl(''));
}
```

**FULL ERROR**

error TS2739: Type 'AbstractControl' is missing the following properties from type 'FormControl': registerOnChange, registerOnDisabledChange, _applyFormState

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Template error Type 'AbstractControl' is not assignable to type 'FormControl'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67834802/template-error-type-abstractcontrol-is-not-assignable-to-type-formcontrol)

Comment: This works https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67834802/template-error-type-abstractcontrol-is-not-assignable-to-type-formcontrol/72517767#72517767

Answer (score 6):

You will need to add stronger typing to your component model.
You can cast your `AbstractControl` as `FormControl` and create a reference to `devices.controls`
Then you can create a method that gets a `FormControl` rather than `AbstractControl`

You can do that by changing your `component.ts` as follows

```
addTerminalGroup: FormGroup;
get terminalNameInput(): FormControl { this.addTerminalGroup.controls.terminalNameInput as FormControl }
get devices(): FormArray { this.addTerminalGroup.controls.devices as FormArray }

constructor(private formBuilder:FormBuilder){
    this.addTerminalGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
        terminalNameInput : new FormControl('', []),
        devices : new FormArray(),
    });
}

addDevice() {
    this.devices.push(new FormControl(''));
}

// Used to get a strongly typed FormControl
getDeviceByIndex(index: number): FormControl {
    return this.devices.at(index) as FormControl;
}
```

Then in your `component.html` you can replace

```
<input type="text" [formControl]="devices.controls[i]">
```

with the following

```
<input type="text" [formControl]="getDeviceByIndex(i)">
```

Answer (score 3):

IDK how to properly fix this error (I bumped into your question by researching this problem I myself was having), here is how I got rid of it:

Remove or set to false the `strictTemplates` option for `angularCompilerOptions` in the **tsconfig.json** file:

```
...
,
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "strictTemplates": false
  }
```

Comment: I also searched and this is the only solution that works.
But it looks more like a workaround than a fix to the problem in my opinion

Comment: @Samshay check out my solution for the correct way to resolve this

Answer (score 2):

As it's not a good solution for disabling the whole string templates, as it's an usefull feature for bug tracing for me. You can just use a any cast for this formControl input  [formControl]="$any(formControl)" or [formControl]="$any(devices.controls[i])" in your case.

The error is caused because of the abstract FieldType in my case.

readonly formControl: import("@angular/forms").AbstractControl;

[Edit]
This should be only a temporary workaround, till the strict template checking works as expected.